# nginx apache tomcat configuration using ssl

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, nginx

I have a public facing nginx server, a apache server in the middle and a tomcat server at the end. At the end the tomcat is listening on 9001 for HTTP traffic  and 9002 for HTTP(S) traffic.

Want to allow HTTP(S) traffic to reach at the tomcat server. My HTTP traffic is working fine on the public IP, however I am stuck with the HTTP(S) part of it.

Unsure what am I missing here.

To summarize:

Public IP HTTP <==> nginx[HTTP] <==> apache [HTTP] <==> tomcat [HTTP] Port 9001 = All Fine

Public IP HTTPS <==> nginx[HTTPS] <==> apache [HTTPS] <==> tomcat [HTTPS] Port 9002 = Failing

Here's my nginx.conf file on the nginx server.

```
 user nginx;
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections 1024

    ;
        }

        http {
                ##
                # Basic Settings
                ##
                sendfile                        on;
                tcp_nopush                      on;
                tcp_nodelay             on;
                keepalive_timeout       65;
                types_hash_max_size 2048;
                server_tokens off;

                # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
                server_name_in_redirect off;

                include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                default_type application/octet-stream;

                ##
                # Logging Settings
                ##
                        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                                                                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                                                                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
                access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        auth_basic "Restricted. Please refer to your environment's release note.";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/demo-env.conf;
}
```

My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/demo-env.conf on nginx box has

```
server{
  listen 80 default;
  server_name  ~^[0-9]*;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  location / {
     proxy_pass         http://10.0.1.215:80/;
     #proxy_redirect    default;
  }
}

server {

        listen 443;
        server_name ~^[0-9]*;

        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

   ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;


        location /  {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://10.0.1.215:443;
#       proxy_cache my-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
        proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
         }


}
```

Here's my apache conf file on the apache server.

httpd.conf file has following entry:

```
Listen 80

Listen 443

Include conf/sites-available/demo-env.conf
```

And demo-env.conf has the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.141:9001/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.141:9001/

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName localhost

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.141:9002/  retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.141:9002/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Any reason for using apache and nginx in front of the tomcat server?

Comment: @semm0, yep.  The tomcat is using hybris commerce suite and hosted in EC2 instance, and will be used for autoscaling.

Comment: okay thanks for this information. Possibly I have some time this evening to think and walk through your current configs. just a guess: any iptables / ufw rules blocking traffic / ip ranges / ip addresses / ports?

Comment: Thanks much @semm0. No, there is no port blocks, all traffic is allowed since this infrastructure is getting built.

Comment: By the way, is there anything that you suggest, that I can look at meanwhile? Any link?

Comment: you can take a look at [Tomcat Clustering Series Part 5 : NginX as Load Balancer](http://www.ramkitech.com/2013/01/tomcat-clustering-series-part-5-nginx.html)

Comment: another note. in your demo-env.conf (apache) you have written in <VirtualHost *:443> section that ProxyPass goes to http://. Wouldn't it need to be https://... with an "s" as it needs to connect via https to Tomcat?

Comment: True. Well, the ssl part is not working anyway...so you can modify it anyway you like it. I will implement your suggestion and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: another guess, but I'm really not sure with this: only nginx delivers a SSL certificate. Wether Tomcat nor Apache deliver one - might this be a problem when proxying a SSL connection from nginx to apache to tomcat?

Comment: I am a newbie to the SSL proxying, hence looking for help. :)

Comment: @semm0, were you able to look into this ?

Comment: sorry for my late response. I wasn't able to recreate your scenario in a VM as I ran out of time. I recommend reading the following two pages:
[1)](https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/loadbalancing/how-to-use-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-server-and-software-load-balancer "How to Use Nginx as a Front-end Proxy Server and Software Load Balancer")

[2)](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/07/08/nginx-load-balancing-reverse-proxy-updated/ "Load Balancing and Reverse Proxying with Nginx, Updated")

In both posts, the Reverse-Proxy and Front-End Proxy parts are of interest.